# Birthday SQL Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datepart

I am trying to create an expression named "Birthday" to use in a given filter that reads "Birthday is equal to @today" to return any birthdays in a given day. The only way to get the birthday is based on the Date of Birth field. Obviously the DOB YEAR differs from the current YEAR. I need help creating a SQL expression that recognizes somebody's birthday without taking the year into consideration.

Comment: Hint:  `MONTH()`, `DAY()`.  But what are you going to do about Feb 29th?

Comment: When you say expression, do you mean a `User Defined Function`, `Stored Procedure`, some ad hoc code, or something else?

Comment: I'm new to the SQL world so forgive my illiteracy...I am running a business intelligence software where I can create a custom "field" by writing a custom SQL expression. So I am trying to write an expression titled "Borrower's Birthday", that returns their MONTH and DAY from their Date of Birth and could match that to the CURRENT MONTH and DAY. Something along those lines, but i'm not sure what logic would work best

Comment: What do you plan on using the birthday for? As others have said, if you only want to indicate the day of their birth, then a birthday of Feb 29 will be fine. But if you want to do something for them every year on their birthday, _technically_ Leap Babies don't have a birthday every year.

Comment: I think indicating the day of their birth is as complex as I'd need. Honestly if we have any borrowers with Leap Birthdays, it wouldn't be terrible if they didn't receive an email every year

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
DECLARE @THEDAY INT = 1
DECLARE @THEMONTH INT = 1

IF OBJECT_ID('BDAY_TABLE') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE BDAY_TABLE

CREATE TABLE BDAY_TABLE (ID INT,
            BDAY DATETIME)

INSERT INTO BDAY_TABLE (ID, BDAY)
VALUES (1, '1/1/2000'),
(2, '2/10/2000'),
(2, '1/1/2010'),
(2, '10/30/2005')

SELECT * FROM BDAY_TABLE

SELECT * FROM BDAY_TABLE 
WHERE DATEPART(DAY, BDAY) = @THEDAY
AND DATEPART(MONTH, BDAY) = @THEMONTH
```

results:

```
1   2000-01-01 00:00:00.000
2   2010-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

Note the use of `DATEPART`, that way we don't really care about the year.

Comment: That should work, but you'll need to include special handling for leap days, unless you're [a pirate named Frederic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pirates_of_Penzance)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DATEADD` and `YEAR` functions to calculate the Birthday in a given year. Supposed that you have a variable `@TODAY` that holds the current date, you could use this as your WHERE clause to get only those people that celebrate their birthday today:

```
WHERE DATEADD(year, YEAR(@TODAY)-YEAR(DOB), DOB) = @TODAY
```

This will also overcome the leap-year problem that way that such people will be returned on March 1st in a non-leapyear.

But most likely you want to get informed on birthdays let's say 2 weeks ahead, so I suggest to indeed calculate the next Birthday in order to be able to use whatever criteria on that, for example:

```
DECLARE @TODAY datetime = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0);

SELECT LastName, FirstName, Email, DOB, Birthday, YEAR(Birthday)-YEAR(DOB) AS becoming
FROM People
  CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (
    CASE WHEN DATEADD(year, YEAR(@TODAY)-YEAR(DOB), DOB) < @TODAY
      THEN DATEADD(year, 1 + YEAR(@TODAY)-YEAR(DOB), DOB)
      ELSE DATEADD(year, YEAR(@TODAY)-YEAR(DOB), DOB)
    END)
  ) bd (Birthday)
WHERE Birthday <= DATEADD(day, 14, @TODAY);
```